# Set ListView Height programmatically in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a **ListView** in my activity's Layout that exists in a **ScrollView** like that:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="4dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@color/article_title"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/add_to_my_resources"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/article_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/article_title"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <Button
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/authors_listView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </ListView>

            <ExpandableListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:divider="@color/light_gray"
                android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
                android:groupIndicator="@null"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:textAlignment="center">

            </ExpandableListView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And I have a List Adapter names **MyListAdapter** that populate my listview:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater =  mcontex.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.txtViewAff = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtViewName.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    holder.txtViewName.setText(name.get(position));
    if (aff != null) {

        holder.txtViewAff.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        holder.txtViewAff.setText(aff.get(position));
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

And **my_list.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1">
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_draw"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to set listview height dynamically to avoid scrolling list view inside the parent layout. So I use this method:

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {

    AuthorsListAdapter listAdapter = (AuthorsListAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight=0;
    View view = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++)
    {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);

        if (i == 0)
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth,
                    LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();

    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + ((listView.getDividerHeight()) * (listAdapter.getCount()));

    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();

}
```

This method works correctly in normal but when **txtViewAff** value is more than 2 or 3 lines, the last item of listview goes behind of the **ExpandableListView**. I add constant value like 40 to my **totalHeight** in method **setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren**:

> totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight() + 40;

but it adds some blank space for normal items that were true without adding 40.

What can I do to resolve this problem?